# How do I use bouncyCastle's CfbBlockCipher?

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, cfb-mode

I am trying to decrypt data that is encrypted with AES in CFB mode using bouncy castle. I am having a hard time.

I have some Java code that initalizes a `StreamBlockCipher` with a `CFBBlockCipher` that contains the `AESEngine` that I use as a reference.

But it is impossible in C# since the `StreamBlockCipher` class checks that the given `IBlockCipher` has a block size of 1 byte.

I tried manually running the data through the `CfbBlockCipher` with this code:

```
var cfb = new CfbBlockCipher(new AesEngine(), 128);
f.Init(false, new KeyParameter(key));
byte[] decrypted = new byte[data.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i += 16)
{
    cfb.DecryptBlock(data, i, decrypted, i);
}
```

But when I got to the final block (which is not divisible by 16 bytes) the code crashes with an exception.

I have tried initializing a `StreamCipherBlock` with this code:

```
var f = new StreamBlockCipher(new CfbBlockCipher(new AesEngine(), 128));
```

But the ctor for StreamBlockCipher throws an exception from [here](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-csharp/blob/9a019087f3e1d21aa5f7a145fb14377e070e3b65/crypto/src/crypto/StreamBlockCipher.cs#L30).

How do I decrypt my blob of data?

Comment: *"But when I got to the final block (which is not divisible by 16 bytes) the code crashes with an exception."* - How about padding the last block with any bytes up to the next block size, encrypting and removing the same number of bytes after decryption? CFB is a streaming mode, so any bytes that come after the actual ciphertext may be thrown away after decryption. This is probably a crude workaround, but it should work.